# What's the most efficient way to send information from a server to my iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, perl, cron, sms

I have a script running every minute (via Cron Job) that sends information to my iPhone. Currently I have it send an e-mail to SMS to my iPhone, but the problem is that sometimes the message is delayed (and I don't receive it for several minutes after it's been sent).

Is there an alternate way to set this up that would allow me to more efficiently receive the information on my iPhone (e.g., developing an app, using a method other than e-mail, etc.)? I'm a novice programmer and am not familiar with too many options, but am definitely open to teaching myself and learning if you point me in the right direction.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Isn't this what the apple push notification service is for? I'm not a iPhone expert either but that's what I've think I've understood through osmosis.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Pushover (https://pushover.net/)? It's an iOS app that has a free trial mode (5 days, if I remember correctly) and it allows you to send push notifications to it via their API.

Comment: Pushover was a brilliant solution! Thank you!

Comment: @user3878370 Glad it helped you. I see you are new here, so I will mention that it is customary to "up vote" any and all answers that were helpful, and to mark one as the answer, if indeed one was the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a CPAN module that may helps you: [Net::APNS](https://metacpan.org/release/Net-APNS)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your notion of "efficiently". Developing an app is of course the most "effective" I'd say -- you can get customized behavior on the response, etc, but it would be expensive in time to produce. Also depending on the behavior you want, e-mail is probably not the most effective, for reasons you already observe. If you just want to view the information that your cron jobs send, then there are already existing apps, such as Prowl: http://www.prowlapp.com

Answer (score 0):

The technology you are looking for is Apple Push Notification Service (APNS). You'll need to write an actual app. You can have an app react to the push notifications with or without an alert view. There are frameworks that can do much of the heavy lifting, both server side and client side, for you.